# Laravel LogOut not working, user gets automatically logged in after requesting secure route

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

When I log out the session data is deleted and user is logged out. However, as soon as any secure resource/route is requested (don't need to log in), such as the below 'user' resource, the user will get authenticated automatically and secure resource returned. In fact, after double checking, the route doesn't even need to be secured with authentication middleware, any route to a controller where a $request->user() instance is used will cause automatic authentication.

Can't understand what could be causing this ? Perhaps the browser is storing credentials in a cookie or elsewhere and sending them each time ? The remember_token field in the database gets automatically populated, even after logging out. Using Laravel 5.1 and angularjs on the client.

```
Route::resource('admin/user', 'UserController', ['before' => 'auth.basic']);
```

**class AuthController extends Controller**

```
  public function getLogout()
    {
        Auth::logout();
        Session::flush();
        return redirect('/');
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**auth.basic** is the a middleware for HTTP Authentication and **auth** is the middleware that checks if a user is logged in. So try this:

```
Route::group(['middleware' => 'auth'], function () {
    Route::resource('admin/user', 'UserController');
});
```

In your case with Angular JS it will return code 401 is the user is not logged in.

Comment: But shouldn't HTTP authentication work just fine with an API based backend ? It's a single request sending username and password unencrypted. If it authenticates, server returns resource, otherwise an error. What I am not understanding is where it's storing the username / password and how to clear it ? Because logout doesn't seem to clear it. Ideally I want to continue using HTTP authentication and after logging out removing the cookie or whatever it is that authenticates the HTTP request with auth.basic.

Comment: @LaserBeak the HTTP Basic authentication won't store the username / password in a session or cookie. It uses fields in the HTTP header to authenticate with the user agent. I'm not sure if you could use it with Angular JS and I strongly recommend you to switch to the standard built in Laravel database authentication.

Comment: I would think auth.basic is using the database just as well, no ? Otherwise how can it authenticate credentials. I plan on using this API with mobile apps just as well, wouldn't switching to auth from auth.basic introduce problems ? Auth uses a HTTP cookie right ?

Comment: Just tried what you suggest and it does indeed register that user has logged out, except it returns a 405 'Method not allowed' , not 401

Comment: @LaserBeak read the laravel auth doc https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/authentication and choose what best suits your application needs.

Comment: Yeah, for browser clients it looks like 'auth' is the way to go. Can probably just add additional routes to the same controllers/methods with auth.basic for use with apps.